# Nested query works in salesforce inspector but not in request with query in url

Tags: soql, api, query, rest, postman

I'am trying to get(request) Accounts with some informations from child called Services__c.
When im performing query in inspector it works fine

`SELECT Legal_Name__c, Name, BillingCountry, (SELECT Service__c, Sub_Service__c FROM Services__r WHERE Service__c = 'Connectivity' AND (Sub_Service__c = 'GSM Signaling' OR Sub_Service__c = 'GSM Signaling Peering')) FROM Account`

But when im adding this query to url and sending get request in postman im receiving

"\nService__c, Sub_Service__c FROM Services__r WHERE Service__c = 'Connectivity'\n                                ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:85\nDidn't understand relationship 'Services__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",

Answer (score 0):

SOQL query appears to be mostly correct, but there is a small issue with the subquery condition. Use IN instead of = when filtering on multiple values for the Sub_Service__c field

Change:

```
SELECT Legal_Name__c, Name, BillingCountry, (SELECT Service__c, Sub_Service__c FROM Services__r WHERE Service__c = 'Connectivity' AND (Sub_Service__c IN ('GSM Signaling', 'GSM Signaling Peering')) ) FROM Account
```

Comment: Didn't help neither, same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Issue kind of solved.
After making REST get call in workbench i discovered that is translated to
`SELECT+Legal_Name__c,+Name,+BillingCountry,+(SELECT+Service__c,+Sub_Service__c+FROM+Services__r+WHERE+Service__c+=+'Connectivity'+AND+(Sub_Service__c+=+'GSM Signaling'+OR+Sub_Service__c+=+'GSM Signaling Peering'))+FROM+Account`
Instead of whitespace pluses are added, it's still doesn't work when sending out from postman. But when making this call from different system it works.